# Converting XML to pandas DataFrame using read_xml

Tags: python, pandas, xml, xpath

I am trying to convert the following XML to pandas data frame using pd.read_xml api.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Request>
    <Employee Name="James">
        <Address>Virginia</Address>
        <Project Name="project1">
            <Description>Description of Project 1</Description>
        </Project>
        <Project Name="project2">
            <Description>Description of Project 2</Description>
        </Project>
    </Employee>
</Request>
```

I tried the following code

```
df1 = pd.read_xml(filename, xpath="./*",parser="lxml")
print("\n"+str(df1.to_markdown))
```

and got the result something like this

```
<bound method DataFrame.to_markdown of     Name   Address  Project
0  James  Virginia      NaN>
```

Similarly when i tried to change the Xpath to read all the elements like below

```
df2 = pd.read_xml(filename, xpath="./*/*",parser="lxml")
print("\n"+str(df2.to_markdown))
```

I got result something like this

```
<bound method DataFrame.to_markdown of     Address      Name               Description
0  Virginia      None                      None
1      None  project1  Description of Project 1
2      None  project2  Description of Project 2>
```

What I am expecting is to get the results in the following format

```
<bound method DataFrame.to_markdown of  
  EmployeName Address      ProjectName              Description
0 James       Virginia      project1           Description of Project 1
1 James       Virginia      project2           Description of Project 2>
```

Is there a way to do this using read_xml api or any other library?

Comment: Why are you looking for 3 records? James got only 2 projects?

Comment: Yes, I think I mistakenly edited, it with 3 records. Actually 2 records are required. I can edit the output. Thanx.

Comment: Yes - please fix the post and show **exactly** how the DF look like.

Answer (score 1):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Request>
    <Employee Name="James">
        <Address>Virginia</Address>
        <Project Name="project1">
            <Description>Description of Project 1</Description>
        </Project>
        <Project Name="project2">
            <Description>Description of Project 2</Description>
        </Project>
    </Employee>
</Request>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = []
emp = root.find('.//Employee')
name = emp.attrib['Name']
addr = emp.find('Address').text
for proj in emp.findall('.//Project'):
  proj_name = proj.attrib['Name']
  desc = proj.find('Description').text
  data.append({'EmployeName':name,'Address':addr,'ProjectName':proj_name,'Description':desc})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
  EmployeName   Address ProjectName               Description
0       James  Virginia    project1  Description of Project 1
1       James  Virginia    project2  Description of Project 2
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. The problem is the structure of the XML can change and the fields like Description, Project Name etc. can be added or removed. Is there a generic approach where we can create the data frame without specifying the column names.

Comment: @JaspritSingh The generic approach is to have a defensive code which will not assume the element or attribute exists. Do you get the direction?

Comment: Can you please help me with an example?